# A simple proof of non-convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

I'm looking for a proof of the following fact:

Suppose $a_n$ is a sequence of complex numbers of the form
$$a_n = \sum_{j=1}^m c_j \alpha_j^n$$
where $m$ is a positive integer and the $c_j, \alpha_j$ are complex numbers with $|\alpha_j|=1$ for each $j=1, \ldots, m$. Assume also that the $\alpha_j$ are distinct. Then, $a_n$ can not converge to $0$.

I think I can cobble together a proof using dynamics on the $m$ torus (i.e. using irrational rotations) but was hoping to find an easier proof. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Just evaluate $\lim \frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|^2=\sum_j|c_j|^2$.

Comment: Such a simple solution - thanks!

Comment: In a different way, if  $\alpha_j=e^{i2\pi r_j}$, and all $r_j$ are rational, then there is a period (there exist $N$ such that all $r_jN$ are integer). Which implies that if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$, then $a_m=0$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$. If $r_i$ are not all rational, then also we can choose $N_0$ so that all $r_jN$ are arbitrarily close to an integer ($\{r_j N_0\} \to 0$ for all $j=1,2...m$). Hence, for $a_{N_0+t}≈a_t, 0<t<N_0$. If $a_n$ converges to $0$, $a_{N_0+t}≈a_t=0, t=1,2...$. Hence, $a_n$ doesn't converge to $0$.

Comment: Another argument is as follows. For $j=1,\dots,m,$ let $u_j\in\ell_\infty$ denote the bounded sequence $(\alpha_j^n)_{n\ge0}$. If there is a linear combination $\sum_{j=1}^m c_ju_j$ of $u_1,\dots,u_m$ which is in $c_0$ then $\|\sum_{j=1}^m c_j\alpha_j^ku_j\|_\infty=o(1)$ as $k\to\infty$.  
By compactness, a subsequence $(\alpha_1^{k_h},\dots, \alpha_m^{k_h})$ converges for $h\to\infty$ to some $(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m)$  such that $\sum_{j=1}^m (c_j\beta_j)\,u_j=0$, but since the $u_j$'s are linearly independent (e.g. by Vandermonde determinant) this implies $c_j=0$ for all $j$.